# Getting ssl socket factory null while using docusign Rest API provided by demo.docusign.net

Tags: sockets, ssl, proxy

I am facing ssl certification error while  using Docusign Rest API privided by ' https://demo.docusign.net ' in IBM websphere . I download ' demo ssl certificate and add from https://trust.docusign.com/certificates

```
I am using api like this....
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("......", 81));
            AuthenticateRequest authReq = null;
            if(appConfiguration == null)
                  authReq = new AuthenticateRequest(configuration);
            else
                  authReq = new AuthenticateRequest(configuration,appConfiguration);

            System.out.println(url);
            logger.debug("url : "+url);
            logger.debug("Request : "+authReq.toJSONString());


            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty(DOCU_SIGN_AUTH, authReq.toJSONString());
            connection.setRequestProperty(ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE);
            connection.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE);


            if(connection.getResponseCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK || connection.getResponseCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {

                  String response = getResponse(connection);
                  connection.disconnect();
                  return response;
            }

****Error found....****
SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends ,

I found soluation , just only set javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS"  to WebSphere Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties

for more information read
http://www.coderanch.com/t/573425/Web-Services/java/javax-net-ssl-SSLException-SSLSocketFactory

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM14425